# VPN connection rejected after switching to ASUS RT-N66U router and different subnet

Tags: router, vpn, windows-server-2008

I had a working VPN setup using my Netgear router to my VPN server (Windows 2008 at **192.168.0.10**). After the router developed problems I switched a new ASUS RT-N66U router.

I configured port forward of port 1723 TCP to my VPN server (now on **192.168.1.10**) but the connection cannot be established! The event viewer on WS 2008 shows the following entry:

> The user domain\user connected to port VPN3-127 has been disconnected
>   because no network protocols were successfully negotiated.

Is there anything else I need to configure in my ASUS router in addition to the port forwarding? Or do I need to change some configuration on the server now that it is on a different subnet (192.168.1.10) than before?